# How does one get the code as a string of an object?

Tags: ruby

I was attempting to do a little metaprogramming and I was wondering how to get the code for an object (or ActiveRecord relation) passed to a method. Ideally, it would return the string of the ruby code. For example:

```
class Bike
end

# Ideal response
get_code_for(Bike.new)
#=> 'Bike.new'

get_code_for(User.where(id: 123))
#=> 'User.where(id: 123)'

get_code_for(Article.published)
#=> 'Article.published'
```

This works for numerics and strings, however, for classes and relations, the arguments are evaluated and return something along the lines of `#<Bike:0x000056338e33fca8>`.

Comment: Nope, this is impossible. Call arguments are evaluated before the call. So if you don't already have `Bike.new` as a string, there's not much you can do.

Comment: If the class is all yours, have a look at `__method__` and `__callee__`.

Comment: The question does not make much sense. If the expression is passed as Ruby code, what means that the code is already evaluated into something, which means there is no way to get that. On the other hand, if it is a string of expression, then you already have it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pointer to a method, you can get that with `Class#method`. This gets you a `Method` instance which has methods such as `#receiver` and `#name`.

```
m = Bike.method(:new)
m.receiver # => Bike
m.name # => :new
m.call # => #<Bike:0x000000017a7078>
format("%s.%s", m.receiver, m.name) # => "Bike.new"
```